# Expected value of maximum of two discrete independent random variables.

Tags: random-variables, expected-value

Let $X, Y$ be a two discrete random variables, $X$ takes values from set $\{0,1,2,...,n\}$, and $Y$ takes values from set $\{0,1,2,...,n,n+1\}$. $X, Y$ are independent.

Let $Z = \max\{X, Y\}$

> Is there a general formula for $E[Z]$?

I know that $P(Z\le t)=P(X\le t)P(Y\le t)$, since they are independent.
I know also that:
$$E[X]=\sum_{m=0}^{n}(1-P(X\le m))$$
$$E[Y]=\sum_{m=0}^{n+1}(1-P(Y\le m))$$
and
$$E[Z]=\sum_{m=0}^{n+1}(1-P(X\le m)P(Y\le m))$$
But i don't know how to relate these equations.

However i belive that there is an answer, because if $X, Y$ were a continuous variables, then we would do the following.

$F_{Z}(t)=F_{X}(t)F_{Y}(t)$

Then we would find a derivative of this product of distirbutions, to get $f_{Z}(t)$ and finally calculate expected value.

Is it possible to convert expected value of discrete random variables into the expected value of continuous variables?

Comment: You found an expression for $\mathbb EZ$. What more do you want than $$\mathbb EZ=\sum_{m=0}^{\infty}(1-F_X(m)F_Y(m))$$? Things are not really better in the continuous case:$$\mathbb EZ=\int_0^{\infty}1-F_X(t)F_Y(t)dt$$

Comment: General question: Why don´t you accept any of the answer to your questions? Don´t you appreciate the work of the users here?

Comment: I don't understand.